# Unable to open any cshtml file in any MVC project visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm start to learning MVC and got problem at the beginning :) I cant open or add any View. If i try to open any cshtml file, it shows me error:

```
The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved
```

Ofcourse document appear in folder. I tried to open cshtml in newly created project and from templates downloaded from microsoft sites. Both gives me the same error. I have done some web research, but any of those solution does not work for me. I tried to modify web.config files, but nothing happend. I've got the same error over and over again.
For now I'am downloading vs2013.4 to reinstall my environment, but i'am realy curious what making error here. Have you got any solutions?

Comment: have you tried restarting your machine ;)

Answer (score 9):

Head to your project's properties, and choose "Web" from the left hand side.

Underneath "Servers", if you're using IIS Express (usually default), you'll have a button that reads "Create Virtual Directory".

Click that and then you should be able to open your views.

Comment: As i said in upper answer comments, i reinstal visual studio to update4.

Comment: I likewise installed update 4 - no joy. Then I did as suggested above and it works. But why? What does having a virtual directory in the project properties have to do with Visual Studio 2013's ability to edit a .cshtml file? Weird!

Answer (score 3):

closing VS and then deleting the solution's .suo file. then restart VS by double-clicking the .sln file i  think this will work for you.

[The project file * has been moved, renamed or is not on your computer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a4c3f944-f36b-4a8d-9cb5-a1133f717ce5/the-project-file-has-been-moved-renamed-or-is-not-on-your-computer?forum=tfsgeneral)

Comment: I tried this with no success. Also it shouldn't appear with every new project.
For now i reinstall visual studio to update4 and it's working fine.